# What is the rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface for?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question came up for not knowing when I should run spin using `node` or `node_base_interface`. Perhaps answering when to use `node_base_interface` might help too.

In C++, it seems that I may use spin with:

```
RCLCPP_LIFECYCLE_PUBLIC
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface::SharedPtr
get_node_base_interface();
```

as in

```
rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor exe;
std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode> node = std::make_shared<SomeClass>();
exe.spin_node_some(node->get_node_base_interface());
```

or I could also use

```
std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node = std::make_shared<SomeClass>();
exe.spin_node_some(node);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343948/what-is-the-rclcpp::node_interfaces::nodebaseinterface-for?/) by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2020-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please add more context to your questions in the future. There's no links to which functions you're talking about, no mention of which language you're using nor what your use case is (what it is that you were trying to accomplish when you ran into this).

---

I guess you mean "what is the `rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface` for"? (https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/7c1721a0b390be8242a6b824489d0bc861f6a0ad/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node_interfaces/node_base_interface.hpp#L35-L36)

The `rclcpp::Node` class has lots of functionality in it, and that functionality is broken into a few pieces to make testing easier (mocking the "node base interface" is a lot easier than mocking the entire node interface) and to make supporting new kinds of nodes easier (the `rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode` is similar but different from the `rclcpp::Node`). The `NodeBaseInterface` has the most basic functionality of a node in it, like getting the node name or namespace, etc...

> This question came up for not knowing when I should run spin using node or `node_base_interface`.

Again, guessing since there's no links, I guess you mean these functions:

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/7c1721a0b390be8242a6b824489d0bc861f6a0ad/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/executors.hpp#L40-L48

**You should always just use the second signature, which takes a `rclcpp::Node`, if possible.**

Like this:

```
auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(...);
rclcpp::spin(node);
```

As is the case in the examples and demos, e.g.:

https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/35674eb17494ab3f67cc5fbe5f127c614be2220b/rclcpp/minimal_subscriber/member_function.cpp#L42

---

However, if you are using something other than `rclcpp::Node` which provides a `NodeBaseInterface` pointer, then you may use the second signature, but this should only be exceptional cases, and normal users should never need to interact with any of the interfaces under normal circumstances. There are still cases where this isn't true, but we're working towards eliminating those cases.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2020-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I know this topic is large and can be relatively confusing, but, rclcpp nodes have a bunch of interfaces. They're around for things like loggers, clocks, graph, etc (https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/tree/master/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node_interfaces) to allow extensions to be created in the future or switch out methods.

The node base interface is one such interface that alot of the implementations require to do their job. Its one of the common building blocks that allow a ROS node to function. When you throw this to an executor (or spin), that's the thing that's going to spin to allow processing of callbacks.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1